# How to display a HTML List

Tags: html, css

Hai,
I need to display like this in HTML
It should be in 2 column format

```
.Apple .Mango
.Orange .Banana
.Grapes
```

Can any one post some sample code or url
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a CSS question, not an HTML question. HTML just defines the list, CSS defines how it looks.

Comment: Isn't this a question for doctype rather then for stackoverflow?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
<div style="float:left">
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please note, that it's highly discouraged to use tables to format your webpage. (That's the reason why I removad that section) It's really better to use `<div>` and `<span>`

Comment: @FUZxxl: I tried this just now and about to post the code which I wrote. Nyway this was the code I was looking. Thanks FUZxxl.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I haven't used div tag because I don't know how to use that. This code was really helpful for me and itz too simple to understand. Thanks again FUZxxl

Comment: @Sanjeev You REALLY need to learn HTML if you're going to be making web pages. It's unacceptable to not know what a div tag is.

Comment: I think you were downvoted for your HTML which belongs in the 90s.

Comment: @Skilldrick : I know div tag. But I always use table instead of div. Now I am trying to make webpages with div tags only. I voted u up and thanks again. :)

Comment: @Skilldrick: I know, that such ind of html is completely outdated, but from a question of this kind you can easily guess, that the user who asked the question may be a freshman to html. So I explained the "oldschool-outdated" an the "recommend" way.

Comment: Abusing tables for layout was a bad idea but done anyway because CSS wasn't around. Now CSS is around people can do it the right way so there is no need to teach people how to do it the wrong way.

Comment: I removed that table stuff. I am really afraid of answering questions if I get down voted because I didn't answered it the "recommend" way.

Comment: A list should be a list, not multiple lists.

Comment: @FUZxxi It's not a matter of 'recommended' or not - there *is* one best method to achieve this, when you look at each solution in terms of cleanliness, browser support and conformity to specifications. Using `table` for this is blatant disregard for the specs, and recommending it to anyone as a solution **will** get you downvoted.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Getting downvotes can feel discouraging, but not answering the "recommended"/right way is pretty much why downvotes exist.  Don't take it personally.  The primary purpose of SO is to collect good answers, not points.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Yes. Next time, I'm going to answer correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this **correctly**. The HTML will stay the same in either case:

```
<ul class="two-col">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
</ul>
```

Now for the CSS. First of all, you can use `float`s:

```
.two-col {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two-col li {
  width: 130px; /* Change this to any amount you want */
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Or you can use the new CSS3 column property (note it is not supported on IE8 and below):

```
.two-col {
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

This will automatically give each column half of their original width. Fiddle around with it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4jLK7/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your stylesheet:

```
li { 
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

You'll probably want to tweak it, but that makes a reasonable starting point.